# i3wm can't create new tiles and mouse won't move

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, mouse

I installed i3wm and X using the tutorials in the Arch wiki for a new Arch installation. I have Intel video, so I installed the xf86-video-intel package (which takes care of the driver).

But when I run: `startx`

I'm taken to i3 (which I've never used before), but the mouse won't move (I'm running Ubuntu dual boot on this machine and mouse works great there) and when I try to create a new tile (`alt-enter`), the cursor turns into what looks like a clock surrounded by a frame of sorts, and doesn't recover. When I try to exit (`alt-shift-e`), I'm presented with a tab asking me to be sure, which I have to click with my mouse, which isn't moving, so I can't exit without shutting down (i.e., pressing the i/o power button on the laptop).

Here is a log from startup. I pressed new window a couple of times and then shut the computer down:

```
06/05/13 01:08:09 - i3 4.5.1 (2013-03-18, branch "tags/4.5.1") starting
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Parsing configfile /home/tjb1982/.i3/config
deciding for version 4 due to this line: # i3 config file (v4)
06/05/13 01:08:09 - [libi3] libi3/font.c Using X font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Used number 1 for workspace with name 1
06/05/13 01:08:09 - auto-starting i3-config-wizard
06/05/13 01:08:09 - startup id = i3/i3-config-wizard/723-0-arch_TIME0
06/05/13 01:08:09 - executing: i3-config-wizard
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Starting bar process: i3bar --bar_id=bar-hjnjco --socket="/run/user/1000/i3/ipc-socket.723"
06/05/13 01:08:09 - executing: i3bar --bar_id=bar-hjnjco --socket="/run/user/1000/i3/ipc-socket.723"
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event
The config file "/home/tjb1982/.i3/config" already exists. Exiting.
06/05/13 01:08:09 - IPC: looking for config for bar ID "bar-hjnjco"
06/05/13 01:08:09 - workspace visible? fs = 0x1bdb0f0, ws = 0x1bdb0f0
06/05/13 01:08:09 - WM_CLASS changed to i3bar (instance), i3bar (class)
06/05/13 01:08:09 - WM_NAME changed to "i3bar for output LVDS1"
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Using legacy window title. Note that in order to get Unicode window titles in i3, the application has to set _NET_WM_NAME (UTF-8)
06/05/13 01:08:09 - This window is of type dock
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Checking window 0x00a00007 (class i3bar)
06/05/13 01:08:09 - dock status does not match
06/05/13 01:08:09 - Checking window 0x00a00007 (class i3bar)
06/05/13 01:08:09 - dock status matches
06/05/13 01:08:09 - ClientMessage for window 0x0000009e
06/05/13 01:08:26 - startup id = i3/i3-sensible-terminal/723-1-arch_TIME366852
06/05/13 01:08:26 - executing: i3-sensible-terminal
06/05/13 01:08:26 - Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event
06/05/13 01:08:28 - startup id = i3/i3-sensible-terminal/723-2-arch_TIME368252
06/05/13 01:08:28 - executing: i3-sensible-terminal
06/05/13 01:08:28 - Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event
06/05/13 01:08:30 - startup id = i3/i3-sensible-terminal/723-3-arch_TIME370387
06/05/13 01:08:30 - executing: i3-sensible-terminal
06/05/13 01:08:30 - Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event
06/05/13 01:08:31 - startup id = i3/i3-sensible-terminal/723-4-arch_TIME371331
06/05/13 01:08:31 - executing: i3-sensible-terminal
06/05/13 01:08:31 - Not a managed window, ignoring UnmapNotify event
[libi3] libi3/font.c Using X font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
```

Contents of ~/.i3/config (replaced `#` with `;` for markdown legibility [which I didn't need to do, but I'm leaving it anyway):

```
; i3 config file (v4)
;
; Please see http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!
;
; This config file uses keycodes (bindsym) and was written for the QWERTY
; layout.
;
; To get a config file with the same key positions, but for your current
; layout, use the i3-config-wizard
;

; Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
; is used in the bar {} block below. ISO 10646 = Unicode

font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1

; The font above is very space-efficient, that is, it looks good, sharp and
; clear in small sizes. However, if you need a lot of unicode glyphs or
; right-to-left text rendering, you should instead use pango for rendering and
; chose a FreeType font, such as:
; font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 10

; use Mouse+Mod1 to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier Mod1

; start a terminal
bindsym Mod1+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal

; kill focused window
bindsym Mod1+Shift+q kill

; start dmenu (a program launcher)
bindsym Mod1+d exec dmenu_run
; There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
; shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
; installed.
; bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

; change focus
bindsym Mod1+j focus left
bindsym Mod1+k focus down
bindsym Mod1+l focus up
bindsym Mod1+semicolon focus right

; alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Left focus left
bindsym Mod1+Down focus down
bindsym Mod1+Up focus up
bindsym Mod1+Right focus right

; move focused window
bindsym Mod1+Shift+j move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+k move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+l move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+semicolon move right

; alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Left move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Down move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Up move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Right move right

; split in horizontal orientation
bindsym Mod1+h split h

; split in vertical orientation
bindsym Mod1+v split v

; enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym Mod1+f fullscreen

; change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym Mod1+s layout stacking
bindsym Mod1+w layout tabbed
bindsym Mod1+e layout toggle split

; toggle tiling / floating
bindsym Mod1+Shift+space floating toggle

; change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym Mod1+space focus mode_toggle

; focus the parent container
bindsym Mod1+a focus parent

; focus the child container
;bindsym Mod1+d focus child

; switch to workspace
bindsym Mod1+1 workspace 1
bindsym Mod1+2 workspace 2
bindsym Mod1+3 workspace 3
bindsym Mod1+4 workspace 4
bindsym Mod1+5 workspace 5
bindsym Mod1+6 workspace 6
bindsym Mod1+7 workspace 7
bindsym Mod1+8 workspace 8
bindsym Mod1+9 workspace 9
bindsym Mod1+0 workspace 10

; move focused container to workspace
bindsym Mod1+Shift+1 move container to workspace 1
bindsym Mod1+Shift+2 move container to workspace 2
bindsym Mod1+Shift+3 move container to workspace 3
bindsym Mod1+Shift+4 move container to workspace 4
bindsym Mod1+Shift+5 move container to workspace 5
bindsym Mod1+Shift+6 move container to workspace 6
bindsym Mod1+Shift+7 move container to workspace 7
bindsym Mod1+Shift+8 move container to workspace 8
bindsym Mod1+Shift+9 move container to workspace 9
bindsym Mod1+Shift+0 move container to workspace 10

; reload the configuration file
bindsym Mod1+Shift+c reload
; restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+r restart
; exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

; resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
        ; These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

        ; Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
        ; Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
        ; Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
        ; Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
        bindsym j           resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym k           resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym l           resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym semicolon   resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        ; same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left        resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down        resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up          resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right       resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        ; back to normal: Enter or Escape
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
}

bindsym Mod1+r mode "resize"

; Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
; finds out, if available)
bar {
        status_command i3status
}

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; automatically start i3-config-wizard to offer the user to create a
; keysym-based config which used his favorite modifier (alt or windows)
;
; i3-config-wizard will not launch if there already is a config file
; in ~/.i3/config.
;
; Please remove the following exec line:
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
exec i3-config-wizard
```

Comment: Could you please post your i3 `config` file? It can be located as `/etc/i3/config` or `$HOME/.i3/config`. You might not have a defined `$TERMINAL` variable or none of the terminals in this list: http://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-sensible-terminal.html

Comment: @ramonovski should I post it into the body of the question or is there some way to attach a file here?

Comment: It could be better if you could post the whole file but I just want to check the line where the `terminal` is specified. It should be like this: `bindsym mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal`. As for the mouse, it could be that you don't have the `evdev` package installed.

Comment: I found this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Common_problems and checked the Xorg log; the mouse driver is missing, etc. (oops). But evdev is there and it seems the keyboard is there, so I'm still not sure about the tiles not being created

Comment: Can you launch `dmenu` (Mod1+d) and launch `i3-sensible-terminal` from there? If not, make sure you have `$TERMINAL` in your shell configuration file or any of the terminal listed in the link I posted in the 1st comment.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I installed xterm and everything seems to work now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure if I have to post an answer to gain some points, should I?

Comment: @ramonovski definitely if you want to gain some points, I will select it.

Comment: If you need to log out and your mouse button isn't working, then you can run the command `i3-msg exit` from `dmenu` or a terminal.  Alternatively, edit your config file so that it logs out automatically without giving the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you launch `dmenu` (Mod1+d) and launch `i3-sensible-terminal` from there? If not, make sure you have `$TERMINAL` in your shell configuration file or any of the terminal listed in the link I posted in the 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the reason was missing mouse drivers and the fact that i did not install xterm. Installing a mouse driver and xterm fixed it for me. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics